# change data key name came from JSON dynamically AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `multi-select` that I made with `angular-ui`.
I want to add an input that user can change the `JSON` key names so for example if the `API` that user add doesn't have "name" instead has "firstName" as the "key name" the app changes that and can work fine.
how can I get this result?
appreciate any help.
 my code is [here](https://thimble.mozilla.org/projects/498921/remix)

what I really want is this: I should add this multi-select as a `widget` to a software named `bonita studio` and it should have an option that user can choose any API that want to use and should have an input field that the user will choose which one of the API's key identifier to iterate. for example if instead of name the user wants to iterate over the email s/he should be able to do. 
I hope this explanation is enough

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.headers = "";

  var counter = 0;
  var chunks = 5;

  $scope.datas = [];

  $scope.getData = function getData() {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "data.json"
      })
      .then(function onSuccess(response) {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          $scope.datas.push(response.data[i]);
        }
        //counter += chunks;
      })
      .catch(function onError(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
      });


  }

  /*$scope.loadMore = function () {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "data.json"
   })
   .then(function loadMoreSuccess(response) {
  for (let i = counter; i < (counter + chunks); i++) {
   $scope.datas.push(response.data[i]);
  }
  counter += chunks;
 })
   .catch(function onError(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
 });
 };*/



  $scope.selected = {
    value: $scope.datas[0]
  };







});
```

```css
#widgetContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#loadMore {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#category {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

#listContainer {
  width: 20%;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h4 {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="script/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" ng-model="headers">
    <ui-select multiple spinner-enabled="true" close-on-select="false" ng-model="selected.value">
      <ui-select-no-choice>
        couldn't find anything...
      </ui-select-no-choice>
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select country...">
        <span>{{$item.name}}</span>
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices group-by="'category'" repeat="data in (datas | filter: $select.search) track by $index" refresh="getData($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
        <span>{{data.name}}</span>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
  </div>

  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Despite I guess this is a good question I really think you need to be more specific.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Please copy the relavent code from the THIMBLE to the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you for saying I thought everyone can see my code

Comment: I changed my thimble address too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Supose you have an object with desired change relations:

var relations = { firstName: "name", oldKey: "newKey" };

// Also, you have your dataArray:

var dataArray = [
  { firstName: "foo", oldKey: 1 },
  { firstName: "bar", oldKey: 2 }
];

// Here follows how you can switch keys:
        
Object.entries(relations).map(([oldKey, newKey]) => {
  dataArray.map(data => {
    data[newKey] = data[oldKey];
    delete data[oldKey];
  })
});

// Check out the result:
console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: works only if you want to change "oldKey" to "newKey" inside the code and if you don't know what is the "newKey" you can't do it inside the code like this. and event if I put input value inside a variable it's not working because this can work with variable "name" not the value

Comment: for example you can't do this: var api_item = "oldKey" ; data.name = data.api_item;

Comment: With few modifications you can populate relations object adding event listener for input change, can't you?

Comment: yes thanks. It worked but I can't use model for it and in order to work I use ng-click on a button that submit that input field (which has ng-model) 's value

Answer (score 1):

Loop over it and create a new key `name` then delete the old one like :

```
jsonData.forEach((data)=>{
      data.name = data.firstName;
      delete data.firstName;
})
```

Comment: I added `ng-change` event to the input and `ng-model="choices"` and in the code above I changed "firstName" to  "choices" but it didn't work.

Comment: @soheilPs The code is doing what you asked in the question, its changing the key `firstName` to `name`.  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to firstName be anything that the user specify in the input field

Comment: because right now any api that I want to use should has name key and I iterate the name but if the api doesn't have name or for example the user want to iterate something else it won't work

Comment: When you get the api response you can use the transformation I posted above to change the response and then use that instead. No?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working. can you test it in my code?

Comment: actually what you said works somehow. if I chenge the code manually for example I create a variable and give it "firstName" and do what you sugested it work and my JSON changes but when I want to change it in the input field that has a `ng-model` it's not working. the problem is in angular code not the javascript.